# How to search mongodb createdAt date using string

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating a search bar using react to find several data fields in mongodb document. I send a keyword from a frontend to NodeJS api to search documents containing that keyword. So far I can search any string value fields. But I want to search createdAt date value also using same search.

For example I want to get all documents createdAt using "2021-26-11" this string value. Below is my mongoose condition

```js
 var condition = title ? { $or: [{ title: { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i" } }, { author: { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i" } },{ createdAt: { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i" } }] } : {};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could get the [timestamp](https://timestamp.online) of created date and in the search put a datepicker and use that timestamp to compare, won't have deal with regex

Answer (score 0):

`var condition = title ? { $or: [{ title: { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i" } }, { author: { $regex: new RegExp(title), $options: "i" } },{ createdAt:  new Date(title) }] } : {};`

You could try this way, But make sure to check

- your `title` is valid date format or not.
- If it's date then make sure to add Greather then that Date and Less than the end of that date - conditions.